# How do I create semi-duplicate rows in pandas based on text data?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, repeat

I see other questions that people asked on this topic, but a lot of the solutions appear to be geared towards some math operation with special built-in functions to handle it (like "repeat"). Im trying to break out text to multiple rows, and it doesn't seem to work.

I have this data:

[image]

I want to break out each Application in each row to its own row, and preserve all the other data. The result would look something like this:

[image]

I tried a few combinations of "stack" or making lists and building new DFs, but I couldn't figure out how to get all the other columnar data with it.

My partial solution below only produces 2 columns instead of all of them (I have about 20 columns and 200k rows of real data).

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,'vuln1','App1;App2;App3'],[1,'vuln2','App1;App2;App3'],[1,'vuln3','App1;App2;App3']]
col = ['Machine','Vulnerability','Application']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Application'].str.split(';').tolist(), index=df['Machine']).stack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I expand the dataframe by semicolon, then use `melt` function to create expected output.

```
df1= pd.concat([df, df['Application'].str.split(';', expand=True)], axis=1)
df1.melt(['Machine','Vulnerability'], value_name='a').drop('variable', 1)

#    Machine Vulnerability     a
# 0        1         vuln1  App1
# 1        1         vuln2  App1
# 2        1         vuln3  App1
# 3        1         vuln1  App2
# 4        1         vuln2  App2
# 5        1         vuln3  App2
# 6        1         vuln1  App3
# 7        1         vuln2  App3
# 8        1         vuln3  App3
```

Comment: Awesome RobJan, thanks!  Never heard of "melt" so i had to research and play around with it using my real data.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

you need [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [df.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
out_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

out_df['Machine']=np.repeat(df['Machine'].values,repeats=len(df['Application'].str.split(';')),axis=0)
out_df['Vulnerability']=np.repeat(df['Vulnerability'].values,repeats=len(df['Application'].str.split(';')),axis=0)

out_df['Application']=df['Application'].str.split(';',expand=True).stack().values
print(out_df)
   Machine Vulnerability Application
0        1         vuln1        App1
1        1         vuln1        App2
2        1         vuln1        App3
3        1         vuln2        App1
4        1         vuln2        App2
5        1         vuln2        App3
6        1         vuln3        App1
7        1         vuln3        App2
8        1         vuln3        App3
```

Comment: Thanks pyd, i haven't dealt with "repeats" yet, so im gonna check it out.  I got it working with "melt", but it never hurts to know another way to skin the panda.